# Shapely polygon buffer problem with 'y' coordinates(double value)

Tags: python, geometry, polygon, contour, shapely

I use shapes to work with contours. I need to add to the contours of different sizes around the field by a given value. Do not scale the contour by a certain percentage, but expand the border by the same given value, regardless of the size of the contour itself.
I am trying to do it like this:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LinearRing
coords = [(30.3283020760901, 59.929340439331035), (30.32625283518726, 59.929669569762034), (30.326617897500824, 59.93065894162025), (30.328354001537814, 59.93056342794558), (30.329838363175877, 59.93089851628186), (30.330225213253033, 59.929729335995624), (30.3283020760901, 59.929340439331035)]
poly_B = Polygon(coords)
poly_A = s.buffer(0.005, quad_segs=10.0, cap_style=1, join_style=2, mitre_limit=10.0)
```

Or like this:

```
r = LinearRing(coords)
poly_B = Polygon(r)
poly_A = Polygon(s.buffer(0.005).exterior, [r])
```

But every time I get a contour in which the Y coordinate is doubled(see image).
Help me figure out where I'm wrong.

[image: contours]

I need the fields of the larger contour to be uniform relative to the smaller one.